# Secure use of exec() with custom class method / function?

Tags: python, security

I’ve written a program with which children (age 12 - 18) can learn to code in Python. It is inspired by a program called PythonKara (https://www.swisseduc.ch/informatik/karatojava/pythonkara/). While PythonKara is based on Jython, I completely coded my version with Python, pygame and tkinter.

With a given set of commands (like *move(), turnLeft(), ...*) the user must maneuver a spaceship to fulfill different tasks which (the more complicated they get) also require Python syntax.
The program has two windows. One window displays the sprites (pygame window) the other one is the editor (tkinter window).

The user input *(self.userInput -> self.userOutput)* is sent to the game loop of the pygame window in order to be executed using the ‘*exec()*’ function of Python. To prevent an advanced user from using Python modules e.g. the ‘os’ module or any other commands that could compromise the system, I parse the user input before it is executed.

My question is whether my ‘*validateUserCode()*’ function is enough to ensure the safe usage of the ‘*exec()*’ function or do I have to implement further security measures?

Code Explanation:

- editor is an instance of the Editor() class that creates the editor
  and parses the user input
- *validateUserCode(self)* is a class method of the Editor() class
- self.userOutput (a modified version of the user input) is sent to game loop (see try - except block)
- in *localvariables* in *exec()* only an instance of Spaceship class that handles all actions related to the spaceship is passed to the *ecec()* function
- except: handles all sorts of exceptions, for clarity I only wrote pass

```
  def validateUserCode(self):
        unsupported_commands = ['import ','print(', 'with ', '.close(', '.read(', '.readline(', 'open(']
        for command in unsupported_commands:
            if command in self.userOutput:
                raise UnsupportedCommandError(command)
```

Code of main loop (pygame window)

```
 try:
    user_code = editor.validateUserCode()
    exec(user_code, local_variables)
 except:
    pass
```

Comment: This is probably not secure.

Comment: This question really has nothing at all to do with pygame or tkinter, since the same question can be asked about a string no matter where it comes from.

Comment: The best way to make this secure is not to use exec and to write a simple parser that understands the commands you want it to. Don't try to blacklist everything that an advanced user may try to do

Comment: You should *parse* the input string using some parser (e.g. the `ast` module if it’s Python syntax) and then only allow *white-listed* functions and expressions instead of attempting to blacklist stuff.

Comment: You can pretty easily fool the validator with clever use of string concatenation

Comment: This isn’t secure. In general restricting arbitrary Python code like this isn’t really feasible, unfortunately. For example to bypass your restrictions I can submit something like `eval('bad string')` and I can construct the bad string with string concatenation to bypass any further filtering. And if you ban eval, I can get it through attribute accesses on existing functions, etc.

Comment: @BryanOakley: You are absolutely right. I changed the tags. But since you are here - your posts about tkinter have helped me a lot writing the above mentioned editor! Big thanks!

Comment: Absolutely not secure. Consider something that runs in a browser if you want to expose the full Python language, like [CodeSkulptor](https://py3.codeskulptor.org/), so there’s already a fundamental level of sandboxing you don’t even have to think about.

Comment: @nneonneo I don´t expect the students to know about the methods you described. Yet it is a valid concern I have not thought about. So I probably need to consider the whitelist poke suggested or go with the ast module (even though I haven't heard or used this particular module yet).

Comment: Also, remember that Python is a language for consenting adults. Before trying to restrict everything, ask yourself what happens if the student does break your security?

Comment: Well, all it takes is one student with some deeper experience in Python to ruin your day, unfortunately. Be very cautious with a whitelist approach - Python is a highly expressive language and it is really easy to accidentally unlock everything. Take a look at https://ctf-wiki.github.io/ctf-wiki/pwn/linux/sandbox/python-sandbox-escape/ for a bunch of ideas on how to escape Python sandboxes and restricted eval()/exec() contexts.

Comment: @nneonneo. With a careful sandbox around python, there's really not much a student can do. You can always run your program in a VM, for example. Then the student really can't do much at all, besides perhaps induce you to reboot.

Comment: Yes, you have to sandbox python itself. Then you’re fine, mostly, as long as you have hard CPU and memory limits. But it’s basically not feasible to sandbox eval/exec from within the language.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is **NOT secure and will never truly be**. See this quick demo:

```
def validateUserCode(user_code):
    unsupported_commands = ['import ','print(', 'with ', '.close(', '.read(', '.readline(', 'open(']
    for command in unsupported_commands:
        if command in user_code:
            raise ValueError(command)

user_code = """
imp = __builtins__.__dict__[f"__{''.join(map(chr,(105,109,112,111,114,116)))}__"]

os = imp("os")
os.system("ls /")
"""

validateUserCode(user_code)
exec(user_code)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> Applications Users        cores        home         sbin         var
> Library      Volumes      dev          opt          tmp
> System       bin          etc          private      usr
> ```

Or if you prefer, a bit more obfuscated one:

```
def validateUserCode(user_code):
    unsupported_commands = ['import ','print(', 'with ', '.close(', '.read(', '.readline(', 'open(']
    for command in unsupported_commands:
        if command in user_code:
            raise ValueError(command)

user_code = """
f=lambda*a,l=(95,)*2:''.join(map(chr,(*l,*a,*l)))
imp = getattr(globals()[f(98,117,105,108,116,105,110,115)],f(100,105,99,116))[f(105,109,112,111,114,116)]

os = imp("os")
os.system("ls /")
"""

validateUserCode(user_code)
exec(user_code)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> Applications Users        cores        home         sbin         var
> Library      Volumes      dev          opt          tmp
> System       bin          etc          private      usr
> ```

Also: the fact that you are trying to blacklist `'print('`, which still leaves `print ("foo")` 100% usable shows that you should not ever bother trying to accomplish this.

Comment: Your code contains the string "import", so will be sanitized

Comment: @MadPhysicist Actually only the string `"import "` would get sanited, and it's extremely trivial to build the word `"__import__"` from the ground up without any resemblance to the word `"import"`.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I did:

1. I tested ruohola's code directly in the editor of my program (python 3.8). It did not work at first because in `exec()` `__builtins__` seems to be already the reference to `builtins.__dict__` so after I modified the code to     `imp = __builtins__[f"__{''.join(map(chr,(105,109,112,111,114,116)))}__"]` everything worked as expected and it of course easily bypassed my weak validation function.
2. I got rid of my validation function and stuck to ruohola´s advice not to bother trying to accomplish a blacklist based on "string validation". Apart from ruohola's code examples I found some more interesting ways to exploit the use of `exec()` following nneonneo's link on how to sandbox python.
3. Since the students only need a small set of Python's `builtins` functions and after some more research I went for a whitelist approach and set `__builtins__` to an empty dictionary and thus disabling its use in `exec()`. So now ruohola's code did not work any longer since it is not possible to use `import`.  The question is whether this approach suffices (cf. 4.)?

   ```
   restricted_env = {
                     '__builtins__': {},
                     'range': range,
                     'kara': spaceship
                    }

   exec(userInput, restricted_env)
   ```
4. Another solution I thought about is packing the files with pyinstaller and excluding the *os* in the spec file. I then would have to rewrite the parts of my code where I use `os.path` and `os.path.join` (if that makes sense?).

If I understand it correctly - the main threat of using `exec()` is the possibility to use the *os* module and thus being able to access and delete (important) files (i.e. relevant for the operating system). But it would not be possible to access files of a different user or would it?

To sum up I thought about the situation at school.

1. Given a computer with python installed - does it even make sense to bother about the secure use of `exec()` in my custom editor if all the unwanted actions can be undertaken in a Python shell anyways?
2. Given a computer with python not being installed - I would have to use e.g. pyinstaller to build an executable file to run it on such a computer. So unless it would be able to "extract" the os module from the files in the pyinstaller folder and making it somehow accessible, assuming my above mentioned whitelist solution is enough, I should be good to go, shouldn't I?

Comment: You would still have to use the AST module to check for dangerous dunder `__` attributes and methods. Even then it is possible to do CPU and memory attacks with infinite loops, math like `1024**1024**1024`, repeating strings like `"abc" ** 1024`, or `"a"´.zfill(1024**1024)`. See the `sys.set_int_max_str_digits` function.